# Initialize a RenderFragment in a partial class in C# Blazor

Tags: c#, .net, blazor

I'm using a component from a third-party package, that accepts a RenderFragment as a parameter, and I want to assign a value to that RenderFragment through a Partial Class of my Index Page.

I realized that when I construct the RenderFragment in the `code` tags, it works. But once you put it in a `partial class`, Visual Studio starts flagging errors.

Example Code that works:

Razor File:

```
<Statistic Title="Feedback" Value="1128" PrefixTemplate="@prefix1" /> 

@code { 
    public RenderFragment prefix1 = @(<Icon Type = "like" />);
}
```

Example code that doesn't work:

Razor File:

```
<Statistic Title="Feedback" Value="1128" PrefixTemplate="@prefix1" />
```

Partial Class:

```
public partial class Index {
    RenderFragment prefix1 = @(<Icon Type = "like" />);
}
```

So my question now is, how do I construct a render fragment in a partial class?
I dont seem to find anything around this subject online.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You use RenderTreeBuilder or stick with doing it in a razor file.

Comment: Thank you for your comment.
I thought of using the RenderTreeBuilder but I think it is very verbose and error-prone. Is there no other alternative?

Comment: No, I prefer to define RenderFragments in a razor file personally - they are markup after all

Comment: Oh okay. Thank you very much. You've been of great help!

Comment: I settled for the RenderTreeBuilder since I'd like to keep my business logic away from the UI

Comment: One last thing: is it advisable to use both the @code in the razor file and that of the Partial Class? Just wondering.

Comment: I don't advise people on their programming style - I can say it is absolutely possible.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I settled for the RenderTreeBuilder, as [Mister Magoo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2658697/mister-magoo) suggested, and since I'd like to keep my business logic away from the UI.

This is how I did it:

Razor File:

```
<Statistic Title="Feedback" Value="1128" PrefixTemplate="@prefix1" />
```

Partial Class:

```
public partial class OperationCard
{
    RenderFragment prefix1 = builder =>
    {
        builder.OpenComponent<Icon>(1);
        builder.AddAttribute(2, "Type", "like");
        builder.CloseComponent();
    };
}
```

Comment: The most important thing to understand here is a `RenderFragment` is not a string or block of html code, it's a delegate.  Any method that implements the pattern `void method(RenderTreeBuilder builder)` can be assigned to a `RenderFragment` property or field.

Comment: Oh okay, that is insightful. Thank you.