# Blazor RenderFragment with HTML in C# codebehind

Tags: c#, blazor-webassembly

I am specifically using Radzen Blazor's [Tooltip](https://blazor.radzen.com/tooltip). It appears that this will let me get what I need. However, I have a table where numerous (but not all) rows will have this tooltip. This tooltip will also have a dynamic set of simple data I need to render within it. Part of which is just normal HTML tag and the other is an onclick event.

The link shows you can do this with the HTML:

```
<RadzenButton Text="Show tooltip" MouseEnter="@(args => ShowTooltipWithHtml(args, new TooltipOptions(){ Style = "color: yellow", Duration = null }))" />
```

And then code on-the-page:

```
@code {
  void ShowTooltipWithHtml(ElementReference elementReference, TooltipOptions options = null) => tooltipService.Open(elementReference, ds =>
    @<div>
      Some <b>HTML</b> content
    </div>, options);
}
```

This works great in their demo, but I have a code-behind and cannot seem to figure out how to do the `@<div>...` HTML part within my method. I thought I could just throw a large string at it that contained all of my HTML but that was just dumb text (no event handlers would work.) I then did a `RenderFragment` but that was not compatible with the `Open` method because it wants a `RenderFragment<TooltipService>` and I could not figure out how to cast or convert to it.

This is what I want to do, I just need to get this to **work in the code-behind** not an on-page `@code` fragment. FYI, the `VirtualizedCell` is just the object that has the content items for the `EquivalentTests` for the foreach loop:

```
@code {
  void ShowTooltipWithHtml(ElementReference elementReference, VirtualizedCell cell, TooltipOptions options = null) => tooltipService.Open(elementReference, ds =>
    @<div style="font-size: 11px">
      <ul class="no-bullets ps-1 mb-0">
        @foreach (var eqTest in cell.EquivalentTests)
        {
          <li class="link-hover">
            <a href="{eqTest.Key}"
               @onclick="@(() => VirtualizedJump({eqTest.Key}))"
               @onclick:preventDefault="@true"
               class="px-1 text-decoration-none">{eqTest.Value}</a>
          </li>
        }
      </ul>
    </div>, options);
  }
}
```

And this is the the HTML to trigger it:

```
<RadzenButton Text="Show tooltip" MouseEnter="@(args => ShowTooltipWithHtml(args, cell, new TooltipOptions() { Style = "color: yellow", Duration = null }))">
```

Comment: You are going to need to turn that block of markup into a render fragment - it's what the Razor compiler does.  My suggestion is to turn on the `EmitCompilerGeneratedFiles` to produce the intermediate files and then review how Blazor compiles the markup in the `@code` block.  You should then be able to build that into a render fragment in your code behind.

Comment: This question has a possible answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69169660/initialize-a-renderfragment-in-a-partial-class-in-c-sharp-blazor

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Initialize a RenderFragment in a partial class in C# Blazor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69169660/initialize-a-renderfragment-in-a-partial-class-in-c-sharp-blazor)

Answer (score 1):

Many thanks to @mrc-aka-shaun-curtis (sorry it is not recognizing the name), I was able to make it work. For those in the future needing this, here is the HTML/Razor code to call the method:

```
<RadzenButton Text="Show tooltip" class="popover-icon" MouseEnter="@(args => RenderTooltip(args, cell)">
  <Icon Name="IconNames.Information" height="12" />
</RadzenButton>
```

And here is the code-behind to get it to work:

```
public void RenderTooltip(ElementReference elementReference, VirtualizedCell cell, TooltipOptions options = null)
{
  var index = 1;

  tooltipService.Open(elementReference, ts => (builder) =>
  {
    builder.OpenElement(index++, "div");
    builder.AddAttribute(index++, "style", "font-size: 11px");
    builder.OpenElement(index++, "ul");
    builder.AddAttribute(index++, "class", "no-bullets ps-1 mb-0");

    foreach (var eqTest in cell.EquivalentTests)
    {
      builder.OpenElement(index++, "li");
      builder.AddAttribute(index++, "class", "link-hover");
      builder.OpenElement(index++, "a");
      builder.AddAttribute(index++, "href", $"{eqTest.Key}");
      builder.AddAttribute(index++, "onclick", EventCallback.Factory.Create<MouseEventArgs>(this, () => VirtualizedJump(eqTest.Key)));
      builder.AddEventPreventDefaultAttribute(index++, "onclick", true);
      builder.AddAttribute(index++, "class", "px-1 text-decoration-none");
      builder.AddContent(index++, eqTest.Value);
      builder.CloseElement();
      builder.CloseElement();
    }

    builder.CloseElement();
    builder.CloseElement();
  }, options);
}
```

Comment: But why?  It would be so much easier to keep a small method in a `@code{ }` section. Using code-behind does not mean `@code` becomes illegal.